# Bash extract some informations in files from a regex

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to extract all languages keys used in my application.

I have files like this :

```
<?php

echo $localisation->lang('MDP_444'); echo $localisation->lang('MDP_666');

echo $localisation->lang('ERROR', true, false);
```

I want to run a command that return:

```
MDP_444
MDP_666
ERROR
```

I tried things like: `grep "lang" * -R | perl -n -e 'while(/(\w*lang\((.*)\)\w*)/g) {print $1."\n"}'` but it didn't works.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -execdir egrep -o -- "->lang\('[^']*" {} \; 
  | sed -e "s/^.*->lang('//g"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use non greedy quantifier :

```
grep "lang" * -R | perl -n -e 'while(/(\w*lang\((.*?)\)\w*)/g) {print $1."\n"}'
                                           here ---^
```

and also the substring you're looking for is in `$2` not `$1`, so:

```
grep "lang" * -R | perl -n -e 'while(/(\w*lang\((.*?)\)\w*)/g) {print $2."\n"}'
```

or

```
grep "lang" * -R | perl -n -e 'while(/\w*lang\((.*?)\)\w*/g) {print $1."\n"}'
```

Comment: `... | perl -nle 'print for /\w*lang\((.*?)\)\w*/g` suffices, but I really don’t trust those `\w*` instances.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Ruby(1.9+)

```
$ ruby -ne '$_.scan( /->lang\(\047(.*?)\047/ ).each{|x| puts x}' file
MDP_444
MDP_666
ERROR
```